# Genetic Algorithms - Travelling salesman

Tags: genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I am going through a past exam paper and I'm trying to understand the following question:

> Assume you have N cities. It's possible to go from each city to any of the other cities. Assume that you have full information about the distances between cities in a tabulated form. The distance between the city number k and the city number l is given by d(k,l); so for example, the distance from the
>   third city to the ninth city is given by d(3,9). Note that d(k,l)=d(l,k).
>
> A travelling salesman needs to visit all N cities and wants to find the shortest route that connects all of the cities. Use a genetic algorithm to solve this problem.
>
> Question: Define an appropriate fitness function for this problem 
>            and say whether high or low fitness is better.

Does anyone know what I need to do for this question? I'm really struggling with where to start and need some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the TSP you want to minimize the distance travelled. There are lots of different ways of travelling the `n` cities; `N! / 2` to be exact.

So if you have `N = 4`, you want an array of the integers `1-4`, each only occuring once. So some possible options would be:

```
[1,4,2,3]
[4,1,2,3]
[3,1,4,2]
```

You then evaluate the score by going from city `i` to `i+1` in the list, computing the distance. Do this for every city `i` in the list (but the last) and you have the total distance; this is your score!

So for the examples above the scores would be:

```
// Please note that the integers 1-4 represent cities
score([1,4,2,3]) = d(1,4) + d(4,2) + d(2,3)
score([4,1,2,3]) = d(4,1) + d(1,2) + d(2,3)
score([3,1,4,2]) = d(3,1) + d(1,4) + d(4,2)
```

You want to minimize the distance, thus minimize the score.

---

You could do this by creating mutation functions that swap two cities in a list for example:

```
[1,4,2,3] -> [4,1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4] -> [1,3,2,4]
```

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3KTWnTrU_c) shows an excellent example of a Javascript implementation of optimizing the distance through a genetic algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!